# Fatal error: Method Magento\Framework\Phrase::__toString() must not throw an exception

Tags: magento2, magento2.2.8

I am using `Magento 2.2.8` and my server's `error.log` is full of below errors

> PHP Fatal error:  `Method Magento\Framework\Phrase::__toString()` must
>   not throw an exception, caught Error: Class
>   'Magento\Config\Setup\ConfigOptionsList' not found in
>   `/magento_setup/vendor/magento/framework/Phrase/__.php` on line 0

**AND**

> PHP Fatal error:  Method `Magento\Framework\Phrase::__toString()` must
>   not throw an exception,
>       caught Error: Class 'Magento\Translation\Model\Inline\Config' not found in
>   `/magento_setup/vendor/magento/framework/Phrase/__.php`
>   on line 0

I have checked many related answers and blogs but didn't found any way to trace it.

Does anyone had faced such errors or have any idea how to trace it?